# To add multiple data in one container in flatlist

Tags: react-native, render, react-native-flatlist

Hello I am new in react native. I am working on flatlist I want multiple items to be shown in list in one container. Example I want to add multiple data in one container. My code is given below any help will be appreciated.

```
this.state = {
  FlatListItems: [
    { key: "Skptricks" },
    { key: "Sumit" },
    { key: "Amit" },
    { key: "React" },
    { key: "React Native" },
    { key: "Java" },

  ]
};
```

and the I have print the key.

```
     <View style={styles.container}>
         <FlatList
            data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
            ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({item}) =>

            <Text style={styles.item} onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)} > 
             {item.key} </Text>        
          }
         />
       </View>
```

i want this kind of layout i have flatlist i want to show thw data like this given in image.[image]

Comment: Hi Shabnam, your code seems correct, can you tell what problem are you facing?

Comment: when i'm running i'm getting only one item i want multiple items in one container of flatlist.

Comment: Like apart from key i want more item how can i add them.

Comment: I am not sure, but checkout https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist if this is your requirement. Thanks

Comment: that's a grid view

Comment: i know but i don't want left side image. i'm working on right one. I have done left one.

Answer (score 1):

Modify state as below, add more items similar to data & key

```
this.state = {
  FlatListItems: [
    { key: "Skptricks", data: "one" },
    { key: "Sumit" , data: "two"},
    { key: "Amit" , data: "three"},
    { key: "React", data: "four" },
    { key: "React Native" , data: "five"},
    { key: "Java", data: "six" },

  ]
};
```

And render it inside the FLatlist as :

```
<View style={styles.container}>
         <FlatList
            data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
            ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({item}) =>(
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.item} onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)} > 
               {item.key} </Text>  
               <Text {item.data} </Text>                   
            </View>    
          )}
          numColumns={2}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
         />
       </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add them as as keys in your sample array of objects. and access them in `item` in your `FlatList` component.

```
FlatListItems: [
  { title: "Skptricks",subTitle:"Asdasd" },
  { title: "melons",subTitle:"melons are great" }
]
```

and in your FlatList component

```
<FlatList
  data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
  ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
  renderItem={({item}) =>
    (<View>
      <Text style={styles.item} onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)} > 
       {item.title} </Text>   
      <Text style={styles.item} onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)} > 
       {item.subTitle} </Text>     
    </View> )
  }
  keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index}
/>
```

Edit: give the `numColumns` prop to `FlatList` Component as

```
numColumns={2}
```

Comment: Make two different FlatList one with numColumns={2} and changed design for Left image sample. and for second one dont give numColumns prop. and design accordingly. with View's flexDirection set to row

Comment: I just want to implement right one left one is grid view i have done that one.

Comment: for second one dont give numColumns prop. and design accordingly. with View's  style with flexDirection set to row.